# Div fading back in when clicking on element

Tags: jquery

I have multiple links, each link has it's flyout when a link is clicked the flyout fades in, and when clicked again the flyout fades out. However, I'm getting the flyout to fade back in when I need it to stay hidden/not visible.

I've gotten pretty far but I just need this little push, I can't figure out what is missing.

How can I make the flyout remain hidden/not visible after its corresponding link is clicked again to hide it?

```js
//Variables
var trigger = $(".trigger");
var flyout = $(".flyout");
var close = $(".close-btn");

$(function() {
  $(trigger).click(function(e) {
    //Hide any other flyout that's visible
    $(this).parents().find(flyout).fadeOut("fast");

    //Toggle active class
    $(this).next(flyout).toggleClass("is-active");

    //Display/hide an actual flyout
    $(this).next(flyout).fadeToggle("fast");

    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  //Fade out the flyout when clicking on the Close button
  $(close).click(function(e) {
    $(this).parent(flyout).fadeToggle("fast").removeClass("is-active");
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  //Fade out the flyout when clicking anywhere on the page
  $(document).click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest(flyout).length === 0) {
      $(flyout).fadeOut("fast", function() {
        //Remove class after animation is finished
        $(this).removeClass("is-active");
      });
    }
  });

  //Fade out the flyout when pressing the ESC key
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
      $(flyout).fadeOut("fast", function() {
        //Remove class after animation is finished
        $(this).removeClass("is-active");
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.flyout {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  background: #eee;
}

.close-btn {
  display: flex;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #999;
  color: white;
}

.is-active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px red;
}


/*Styles not needed for demo*/

.flyout-module {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  overflow: visible;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flyout-module">
  <a href="#" class="trigger">Link</a>
  <div class="flyout flyout-tags">
    <p>content goes here</p>
    <p>content goes here</p>
    <p>content goes here</p>
    <a href="#" class="close-btn" title="Close"><span>×</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flyout-module">
  <a href="#" class="trigger">Link</a>
  <div class="flyout flyout-tags">
    <p>content goes here</p>
    <p>content goes here</p>
    <p>content goes here</p>
    <a href="#" class="close-btn" title="Close"><span>×</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flyout-module">
  <a href="#" class="trigger">Link</a>
  <div class="flyout flyout-tags">
    <p>content goes here</p>
    <p>content goes here</p>
    <p>content goes here</p>
    <a href="#" class="close-btn" title="Close"><span>×</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rzea/hn9cdf34/25/

Thanks.

Comment: Since you're setting an "isActive" flag, you could check that. If the div is already active when you click on the link, hide it.

Comment: Although I'm not that good a JS, your answer inspired me to come up with a solution. I solved it by modifying this line `$(this).parents().find(flyout).fadeOut("fast");` to this `$(this).parent().siblings().find(flyout).fadeOut("fast"`); - I needed to 'go outside' the trigger element to its parent container, then look for the siblings of that container, and inside look for the flyout and fade it out. Here's the fixed fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rzea/hn9cdf34/34/ - Thank you!

Comment: Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue.

It was a matter of properly 'traversing' the DOM.

As I mentioned above, I needed to 'go outside' the trigger element to its parent container, then look for the siblings of that container, and inside look for the flyout and fade it out.

Here's the fix:

```
//Hide any other flyout that's visible
$(this).parent().siblings().find(flyout).fadeOut("fast", function(){
    //Remove class after animation is finished
  $(this).removeClass("is-active");
});
```

The old line that didn't work looked like this (this is only for reference):

```
$(this).parents().find(flyout).fadeOut("fast");
```

Here's the fixed fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rzea/hn9cdf34/37/

Thanks to @camainc, his answer inspired me to come up with the fix :)